# 504 : Gateway Timeout with urllib2

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, http-status-code-504

When I try to read the source of the page , I get the following output

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "price.py", line 179, in <module>
    l_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(l_link).read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 504: Gateway Time-out
```

My code.py (After removing irrelevant stuff) :

```
isbn = str(9780593072493)
l_link = "http://www.landmarkonthenet.com/books/search/"+isbn
l_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(l_link).read())
l_temp = l_soup.select(".price-current")
```

How can I resolve this ?
Is the redirection of l_link causing problem over here ? Thanks in Advance.

PS : I've already searched for the problem and couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: What is your program? it is a client server and php server connected to different network? Please specify what is the goal of your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[5xx status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_http_status_codes#5xx_Server_Error) are problems with the server (compared with 4xx status codes, which are problems with the client).  This means you sent the server a valid request, but the server was unable to serve a valid response.

Your code is fine, but the server (or in this case, a gateway that the server is using) is having problems.  You just need to wait patiently for the server to resolve its own issues, or contact the server administrator and inform them that their server is misbehaving.

Comment: `u_link = "http://www.uread.com/search-books/"+isbn`


`u_soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(u_link).read())`


`u_temp = u_soup.find(id="ctl00_phBody_ProductDetail_lblourPrice")`

The same thing happens with this also , though both the servers respond fine when the request is sent from a browser. :(

Comment: @GingerNinja23: Your code works fine for me.  Are you able to download the URL from the command line, e.g. `curl -L http://www.landmarkonthenet.com/books/search/9780593072493`?  Have you tried using Wireshark to trace the packets being sent to make sure everything is as you expect?

Comment: Thanks for the help Adam. I was trying the code on koding.com and it wasn't working there for some reason. I've tried it on my PC now. Both curl and the code work fine :)